# Da Vinci Raw to Blender and back to Da Vinci

Tags: davinci-resolve, workflow, colorspace

I need to make a vfx shot that requires using the video itself as a texture for a wall breaking (basically projecting the original footage onto the tracked CGI wall). The clip on my timeline is BRAW. What is the best way to do the round trip so that my CGI plate has still enough information for color grading and overall compositing in fusion?

1)Should I send it to Blender in log?

2)What color space should I export it in?

I usually color manage my projects in Da Vinci WG through nodes.